# Trying my first sql left join - isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hi
I'm trying to join two database table and extract the rows to php variables. But it's my first join function, and I'm not getting any values returned to my form.

```
SELECT    s.supplierid,
          s.name, 
          s.address, 
          s.zipCode, 
          s.cityName, 
          s.region, 
          s.country, 
          s.phone, 
          s.fax, 
          s.contactMame, 
          s.contactTitle, 
          s.contactPhone, 
          s.contactEmail, 
          s.notes, 
          s.employeeid, 
          e.employeeid as emp_id, 
          e.name as emp_name
FROM      suppliers s
LEFT JOIN employees e
ON        s.employeeid=e.employeeid
WHERE     supplierid=? limit 0,1
ORDER BY  name DESC
LIMIT     :from_record_num, :records_per_page";
```

And then I assign them to variables like this

```
$name = $row['name'];
$address = $row['address'];
$emp_name = $row['emp_name'];
```

I need to use it another time in my code, but to extract all rows from the table. Is there a way to use

```
SELECT *
```

in a left join?

Comment: Your problem isn't really clear.  What do you mean when you say, "it's not quite doing what I want it to do." ?

Comment: and yes, you can use `SELECT *` in a left join

Comment: And yes, you can use a SELECT * in a query that includes a LEFT JOIN.  But care must be taken if the same field (eg. 'name') exists in both tables.

Comment: You're right wasn't quite clear. I'm not getting any values to my html form.

Comment: it appears you have two limit clauses in the sql. Also, to avoid problems, use the alias when you reference the field name in the where clause and also the order by. You cannot use placeholder vars in the sql for the limit clause either

Comment: and if i remember php correct you should also use `$name = $row['s.name'];`

Comment: I think your SQL is failing due to a syntax error. *Try it in the MySQL console or PHPMyAdmin.* I don't think you can have a LIMIT clause after WHERE and after ORDER BY both.

Comment: no, you don't need to use the alias when referencing the fields in php

Comment: Also you're mixing the use of `?` and of named `:var` for your parameterization....I don't think any database library in PHP allows using both at the same time.

Comment: Now it's working. I had to delete the ORDER BY and the LIMIT lines, and also the extra limit in the WHERE line.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-
( assumes pagination vars `$from_record_num` and `$records_per_page` )

```
$sql="select   
  s.supplierid,
  s.name,
  s.address,
  s.zipcode,
  s.cityname,
  s.region,
  s.country,
  s.phone,
  s.fax,
  s.contactmame,
  s.contacttitle,
  s.contactphone,
  s.contactemail,
  s.notes,
  s.employeeid,
  e.employeeid as 'emp_id',
  e.name as 'emp_name'
    from suppliers s
    left join employees e on s.employeeid=e.employeeid
    where s.supplierid=?
    order by  s.name desc
    limit {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";
```